# Braintree::ConfigurationError (Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id needs to be set)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, braintree

I only get that error when I run my app in production(Heroku). Locally run ok, I already tested some transactions and it works. I use a Braintree sandbox account

To be specific I get the following error:

```
2015-05-18T19:07:53.077006+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/transactions/new" for 160.9.0.125 at 2015-05-18 19:07:53 +0000
2015-05-18T19:07:53.093436+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-05-18T19:07:53.095900+00:00 app[web.1]: Braintree::ConfigurationError (Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id needs to be set):
2015-05-18T19:07:53.095898+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-18T19:07:53.095902+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:54:in `generate_new_client_token'
2015-05-18T19:07:53.095903+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:9:in `new'
2015-05-18T19:07:53.095905+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-18T19:07:53.095906+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-18T19:07:53.089739+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by TransactionsController#new as HTML
2015-05-18T19:07:53.094330+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
```

So my question is If I can use a braintree sandbox account in production or I need to switch to a production account in braintree? Is sandbox causing the error?

**config/initializers/braintree.rb**

```
 Braintree::Configuration.environment = :sandbox
  Braintree::Configuration.logger = Logger.new('log/braintree.log')
  Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id = ENV['BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID']
  Braintree::Configuration.public_key = ENV['BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY']
  Braintree::Configuration.private_key = ENV['BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY']
```

**config/application.yml**

```
# Braintree configuration keys
  BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
  BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Comment: I work at Braintree. This looks similar to the problem you had in your other question, are you sure you're configuring Braintree in your "prod" environment? You can definitely use the Braintree sandbox for testing in any env you want, but it's generally not a good idea to do in production so you don't accidentally send it real customer / credit card data.

Comment: I have config/initializers/braintree.rd which takes the credentials from config/application.yml

Comment: I suggest you [email our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) with your complete code. It looks like you're not setting the configuration in your production environment.

Comment: do I need more that those 2 files (braintree.rb, application.yml) to run in production?

Comment: You need to be careful when you say "production". Do you mean your production env (Heroku) or ours (as opposed to our sandbox environment). You don't need any different code for production than Sandbox, just different credentials. So the values for merchant ID, public key, and private key should be different, but everything else should be the same.

Comment: I mean heroku production. I have edited the post and I have added those 2 files.

Comment: Can you add the code that loads the `application.yml`? It doesn't automatically get added to `ENV`, as far as I know. Maybe in your `application.rb`?

Comment: Thank you SOoooooo much. The error was with Figaro gem that I am using which do that automatically using ENV and application.yml. I run "rake figaro:heroku[intense-harbor-8486]" in my console and everything running ok. I didn't know that i needed to do that since all gems install in heroku server when I push my app

Comment: Great! You can post an answer yourself and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The error was with Figaro gem that I am using which do that automatically using ENV and application.yml. I run "rake figaro:heroku[intense-harbor-8486]" in my console and everything running ok. I didn't know that i needed to do that since all gems install in heroku server when I push my app –